# How to replace character "." to "," on keyboard when focus on Entry Field on Xamarin Forms (iOS)?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How to replace character `","` to `"."` on keyboard when focus on Entry Field on Xamarin Forms?
I find way replace `"Next"` to `"Done"` on keyboard.

[Change return to be next/done key in Xamarin Forms Shared Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445473/change-return-to-be-next-done-key-in-xamarin-forms-shared-project)

Don't know that can replace `","` to `"."` when focus `Entry` (with display keyboard is `"Numeric"`):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a03yz.png)

If you know it on Android and iOS, you can help me!

Please help me! Tks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to go through this stress at all.
Since you have the keyboard changed to *numeric*, simply let the OS determine the layout.

Now when you get the Entry.Text, simply replace the occurrences of (,) to (.). 
To make it real-time, do this in the Entry.TextChanged Event.

```
Entry.Text?.Replace(',', '.');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The "?" ensures that if the Entry.Text is NULL, the code doesn't break.

Comment: I like your idea, but I have problem when test on multi device as Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge. Therefore, I think that more handle. But Your idea is very good (like)

Comment: Can you better explain this further problem you are facing?

Comment: When change language of device Android (Samsung S7 Edge), keyboard can't change "." to "," . So that can't input value "1,23". I fixed it, thanks you.